# Doctrine 2.4 not removing orphan slave ManyToMany relationship objects

Tags: doctrine-orm

could someone point why orphanRemoval is not working for the following ManyToMany relationship?

I mean, middle many_to_many table get its rows created/updated/removed but end/slave table does not removes orphan rows.

Thanks a lot, heres is my mapping

```
    Class TaskRecursive
    {
        /**
         * @Assert\Valid
         * @ORM\ManyToMany( targetEntity="TaskAttachment", inversedBy="tasks", cascade={ "persist" }, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EAGER" )
         * @ORM\JoinTable(
         *      name="tasks_attachments",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE" )},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_attachment_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         * )
         */
        private $tasksAttachmentsTask;


    Class TaskAttachment
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany( targetEntity="TaskRecursive", mappedBy="tasksAttachmentsTask" )
         */
        private $tasks;
```

Note i'm not using cascade={"remove"} as i don't want inverse side objects to be removed when an owning side object is removed, i want inverse side objects removed when it has no more relationships with owning side objects.

WORKAROUND:
In my controller i explicitly call `$taskRecursive->setTasksAttachmentsTask( $taskAttachments )` to replace the whole collection so i edited that method to remove orphan collection's objects by hand:

```
    /**
     * Set tasksAttachmentsTask
     *
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $taskAttachmentsTask
     * @return TaskRecursive
     */
    public function setTasksAttachmentsTask( \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $taskAttachments )
    {
        if( $taskAttachments != $this->tasksAttachmentsTask )
        {
            foreach( $taskAttachments as $tasAttachment )
            {
                $tasAttachment->addTaskRecursive( $this );
            }
            $this->_onPropertyChanged( 'tasksAttachmentsTask', $this->tasksAttachmentsTask, $taskAttachments );

            //Orphan removal is not working fine, so le'ts removed orphan objects by hand
            foreach( $this->tasksAttachmentsTask as $ta )
            {
                if( !$taskAttachments->contains( $ta ) && $ta->getTasks()->count()  < 2 )
                {
                    $this->tasksAttachmentsTask->removeElement( $ta );
                }
            }

            $this->tasksAttachmentsTask = $taskAttachments;
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Can you try removing the eager removal? Also, try tracking scheduled removals in the `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork` after removing an item from `TaskRecursive#tasksAttachmentsTask` to verify that a deletion was actually scheduled (this happens before `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager#flush()` is called

Comment: i tried listening onFlush::$eventArgs->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityDeletions() and also getScheduledCollectionDeletions() plus getScheduledCollectionUpdates()  but there were not entities scheduled for removal.

Comment: Are there any calls to https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/f197a9c9f140a06f399fc05d7149220d04eb3a56/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php#L424 ?